# Can you cache data to view it offline later?

Tags: objective-c, ios, caching

I've made an app that when connected to the internet, it downloads video's, pdf's, images from an ftp server. It currently stores the data in the document directory (it can be around 50mb for example). It works fine.

Now I have a feeling that this is against apple's guidelines and the app will be rejected from the app store, is my feeling right?

Now if what I've read is right, my app would be allowed in the app store if this data is stored in the cache folder, right? Now my question is, can I just change the directory for storage to cache? Are there limitations when it comes to size? Will the files still be available when the app was shut down and restarted at a moment when there is no connection? Can the device or other apps remove data from the cache?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our app got rejected last year for the same reason. However, downloading stuff to the cache folder instead of documents was enough to get it accepted. There are some things to keep in mind, though.

First of all, this is a must-read: https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/

As far as i know, there are no size limitations for the cache folder, so you could go on storing the same stuff as you did previously in the documents, nobody would care. On the other hand, the cache folder is subject to be emptied by the system whenever it finds that there is too little space remaining.

From the File System Programming Guide:

> [The Caches folder] Contains cached data that can be regenerated as needed. Apps should never rely on the existence of cache files.

I read somewhere (unfortunately lost the source) that data stored in the cache are guaranteed to be persistent during a session, that is, from the time the user launches/switches to your app till it is sent to the background/terminated. This means it could easily happen that when your app becomes active it finds a completely empty cache folder. You should be prepared to handle that.